# I am getting a UWP App Compiler Error ILT0038 in x64 Release mode but not Debug mode

Tags: debugging, uwp, release

I have a UWP app that compiles and runs fine in debug mode, but when I compile in x64 release mode, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source
> Error       ILT0038: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting.AutoFormattingOptions' is a value type with a default constructor. Value types with default constructors are not currently supported. Consider using an explicit initialization function instead.

I do have Microsoft.CodeAnalysis analyzers installed, but they should have no effect while compiling, right?

Has anyone seen this before or have any idea how to resolve? Any help appreciated.

---

EDIT - updated, I originally noted x86, but actually x64.

Comment: You could try to contact the .NET Native team and send them a repro about this. Please refer to this: [.NET Native Internal Compiler Errors](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/Documentation/ilcRepro.md#known-issues)

Comment: Thanks.  I have initiated a conversation with the visual studio team.  We will see how this goes.  I have found that removing the analyzers makes the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is the best answer, but it did 'fix the problem'.  I added ExcludeAssets to project folder as such:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis">
      <Version>4.4.0</Version>
      <ExcludeAssets>All</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

I am unsure of the long-term consequences to this, but it also removed several warnings and allowed me to remove additional references that were being demanded by Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, but only in Release mode.